# convert muti-dimension nsmutablearray into single-dimension nsmutablearray

Tags: ios, ipad, nsmutablearray

In IOS, I have this array:

```
multiDimensionArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:[NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"one",@"two", nil],[NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"three", nil],[NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"four", nil],nil];
```

Then I need to convert it to:

```
singleDimensionArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:[multiDimensionArray objectAtIndex:0], nil];
```

Instead of getting 2 objects(@"one" and @"two") I get 1 object (@"one, two"). How can I make it into 2 objects? Thanks!

Comment: Your code is correct, check your debugging.  The above code will produce two objects.

Comment: I did nslog the count is 1.

Answer (score 0):

Your new array just contains an array with the 2 extra objects. So now do the same thing to create the new array with 2 objects.

```
twoObjectsArray = [singleDimensionArray objectAtIndex:0];

for (NSString *string in twoObjectsArray) {
    NSLog(@"%@,string);
}
```

Comment: Hi MarkM: your way works. But I don't understand what is the different? Do you care to explain in a bit more details? Thanks!

Comment: Your NSLog probably shows the results of the one array, which contains 2 objects, not 1. Since you are viewing an array the result will be 1 of the NSLog but that 1 result contains 2 objects.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSMutableArray *array1=[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"One",@"Two", nil];

NSMutableArray *array2 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Three",@"Four" ,nil];

NSMutableArray *array3 =[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:array1,array2, nil];

NSMutableArray *array4=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for (NSMutableArray *array in array3)
{
    for (int i=0; i<[array count]; i++)
    {
        [array4 addObject:[array objectAtIndex:i]];
    }
}

NSLog(@"Final Array = %@",array4);

array3=nil;
array2=nil;
array1=nil;
```